# Reading Ninject WithConstructorArguments from Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, ninject

I have the following RegisterServices function:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<ISearchRepository>().To<SearchRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<ITagRepository>().To<TagRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IStore>().To<Store>()
        .WithConstructorArgument("dbId", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseId"])
}
```

Using breakpoints I can confirm that `ConfigurationManager` is correctly populating the value.

However, when running I get the following exception when the kernel finishes binding:

[image]

If I replace the `ConfigurationManager` reference with a constant the application runs fine.

I don't want to lose the ability to configure Ninject through a config file, is this a limitation of Ninject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such limitation of Ninject.

I suppose the problem is that `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseId"]` returns `string` and your `dbId` argument is of type `int` (or some other non-string type).

Try:

```
var databaseId = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseId"]); 
kernel.Bind<IStore>()
      .To<Store>()
      .WithConstructorArgument("dbId", databaseId);
```